# How do I select an absent column using a literal using SOQL?

Tags: salesforce, soql

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
SELECT
  Id, 
  '1999-01-01T23:01:01Z' for Some_New_Date_Field__c,
  SystemModstamp
FROM Opportunity
```

`Some_New_Date_Field__c` has not been added to `Opportunity` yet, but I would like to return a literal value for this for now to unblock some downstream engineering work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to include a literal return value for a column in SOQL, and you also cannot set values for arbitrary property names on returned sObjects.

In Aggregate SOQL, but not non-aggregate queries like this one, you can provide a name for a value that's used in the returned `List<AggregateResult>`; for example, you could do

```
SELECT OwnerId, MAX(CloseDate) largestCloseDate FROM Opportunity GROUP BY OwnerId
```

and get back `AggregateResult` objects that have a property `largestCloseDate`. I don't think that helps you here.